# Comunicação de um projeto Windows Service com um projeto Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-service

Acabei de desenvolver um projeto Windows Service(este irá ficar rodando para verificar atualizações do sistema, via ClickOnce). Preciso que esse Windows Service comunique com um Form. Sei que não é possível criar um Form dentro de um Serviço. Qual a maneira mais segura de fazer esse Serviço comunicar com um projeto Windows Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome disso é **[comunicação entre processos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos)** ([IPC, em inglês: Interprocess Communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).

Pode ser feita de várias formas:

- Sockets
- Named Pipes
- Arquivos mapeados em memória
- entre outras

Vou mostrar como fazer usando Named Pipes, tomando como base o [esta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054851/195417), levemente alterado para ser funcional (pois o cara lá não testou a resposta, mas eu sim).

O exemplo consiste em duas aplicações de Console se comunicando, mas poderiam ser qualquer tipo de aplicação, ou seja, se aplica perfeitamente ao seu caso.

São duas classes principais:

- **`PipeServer`**: permite servir vários clientes com um mesmo named pipe
- **`PipeClient`**: permite conectar num servidor de named pipe

O exemplo consta em trocar numeros entre o cliente e o servidor, sendo que cada parte incrementa o número com um aleatório de 0 até 10 e manda de volta para o outro lado.

Você pode iniciar o servidor, e depois iniciar vários clientes. O servidor irá imprimir na tela os números que recebe e envia para os clientes, e os clientes farão o mesmo.

- Print da minha tela com 1 servidor e 3 clientes rodando:

  [image: Tela com 1 servidor e 3 clientes]

  - Cada cliente possui apenas fonte de uma cor
  - O servidor possui uma fonte de cada cor, correspondendo às cores dos clientes

## NamedPipesServer.csproj

- **PipeServer.cs**

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO.Pipes;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace NamedPipesServer
  {
      public class PipeServer
      {
          private Thread runningThread;
          private volatile bool pareAssimQuePossivel;

          public string PipeName { get; private set; }

          public PipeServer(string pipeName)
          {
              this.PipeName = pipeName;
          }

          private void ServerLoop()
          {
              while (!this.pareAssimQuePossivel)
                  this.ProcessNextClient();
          }

          public void Iniciar()
          {
              this.runningThread = new Thread(this.ServerLoop);
              this.runningThread.Start();
          }

          public void Parar()
          {
              this.pareAssimQuePossivel = true;
          }

          public void Abortar()
          {
              this.runningThread.Abort();
          }

          private void ProcessClientThread(object o)
          {
              using (var pipeStream = (NamedPipeServerStream)o)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      this.OnProcessClient(pipeStream);
                  }
                  finally
                  {
                      pipeStream.WaitForPipeDrain();
                      if (pipeStream.IsConnected)
                          pipeStream.Disconnect();
                  }
              }
          }

          public event ProcessClient ProcessClient;

          protected virtual void OnProcessClient(NamedPipeServerStream o)
          {
              if (this.ProcessClient != null)
                  this.ProcessClient(this, o);
          }

          private void ProcessNextClient()
          {
              try
              {
                  var pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(this.PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, -1);
                  pipeStream.WaitForConnection();

                  // Spawn a new thread for each request and continue waiting
                  var t = new Thread(this.ProcessClientThread);
                  t.Start(pipeStream);
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  // If there are no more available connections
                  // (254 is in use already) then just
                  // keep looping until one is available
              }
          }

          public void EsperarAteDesconectar()
          {
              if (this.runningThread != null)
                  this.runningThread.Join();
          }
      }

      public delegate void ProcessClient(PipeServer sender, NamedPipeServerStream stream);
  }
  ```
- **Program.cs**

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.IO.Pipes;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace NamedPipesServer
  {
      static class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              var server = new PipeServer("MeuNamedPipe");
              server.ProcessClient += ProcessClient;
              server.Iniciar();
              server.EsperarAteDesconectar();
          }

          private static volatile int number;
          private static ConsoleColor[] colors = new []
                                                 {
                                                     ConsoleColor.Blue,
                                                     ConsoleColor.Cyan, 
                                                     ConsoleColor.Green, 
                                                     ConsoleColor.Magenta, 
                                                     ConsoleColor.Red, 
                                                     ConsoleColor.White, 
                                                     ConsoleColor.Yellow, 
                                                 };

          private static object locker = new object();

          private static void ProcessClient(PipeServer sender, NamedPipeServerStream stream)
          {
              var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
              var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

              var random = new Random();

              var color = colors[Interlocked.Increment(ref number)];
              writer.WriteLine(color);

              int num = 0;
              while (true)
              {
                  num += random.Next(10);
                  lock (locker)
                  {
                      Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                  Console.WriteLine("Send: " + num);
                  }
                  writer.WriteLine(num);
                  writer.Flush();
                  stream.WaitForPipeDrain();

                  Thread.Sleep(1000);

                  var recv = reader.ReadLine();
                  lock (locker)
                  {
                      Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                      Console.WriteLine("Received: " + recv);
                  }
                  var recvNum = int.Parse(recv);
                  num = recvNum;

                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

## NamedPipeClient.csproj

- **PipeClient.cs**

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO.Pipes;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace NamedPipeClient
  {
      public class PipeClient
      {
          private Thread runningThread;
          private volatile bool pareAssimQuePossivel;

          public string PipeName { get; private set; }

          public bool PareAssimQuePossivel
          {
              get { return this.pareAssimQuePossivel; }
          }

          public PipeClient(string pipeName)
          {
              this.PipeName = pipeName;
          }

          private void ClientProcessorThread()
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      using (var pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", this.PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut))
                      {
                          pipeStream.Connect(10000);
                          try
                          {
                              this.OnProcessServer(pipeStream);
                          }
                          finally
                          {
                              pipeStream.WaitForPipeDrain();
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  catch (Exception e)
                  {
                      // If there are no more available connections
                      // (254 is in use already) then just
                      // keep looping until one is available
                  }
              }
          }

          public void Iniciar()
          {
              this.runningThread = new Thread(this.ClientProcessorThread);
              this.runningThread.Start();
          }

          public void Parar()
          {
              this.pareAssimQuePossivel = true;
          }

          public void Abortar()
          {
              this.runningThread.Abort();
          }

          public event ProcessServer ProcessServer;

          protected virtual void OnProcessServer(NamedPipeClientStream o)
          {
              if (this.ProcessServer != null)
                  this.ProcessServer(this, o);
          }

          public void EsperarAteDesconectar()
          {
              if (this.runningThread != null)
                  this.runningThread.Join();
          }
      }

      public delegate void ProcessServer(PipeClient sender, NamedPipeClientStream stream);
  }
  ```
- **Program.cs**

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.IO;
  using System.IO.Pipes;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace NamedPipeClient
  {
      static class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              var client = new PipeClient("MeuNamedPipe");
              client.ProcessServer += ProcessServer;
              client.Iniciar();
              client.EsperarAteDesconectar();
          }

          private static void ProcessServer(PipeClient sender, NamedPipeClientStream stream)
          {
              var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
              var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

              var random = new Random();

              var colorStr = reader.ReadLine();
              var color = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colorStr);
              Console.ForegroundColor = color;

              int num;
              while (true)
              {
                  var recv = reader.ReadLine();
                  Console.WriteLine("Received: " + recv);
                  var recvNum = int.Parse(recv);
                  num = recvNum;

                  Thread.Sleep(1000);

                  num += random.Next(10);
                  Console.WriteLine("Send: " + num);
                  writer.WriteLine(num);
                  writer.Flush();
                  stream.WaitForPipeDrain();

                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Me falaram para fazer por Startup. Não intendi muito bem esse conceito. Vicê já ouviu falar?

Answer (score 1):

Meu conselho é: Use socket UDP
Sempre que for possível escolha métodos assíncronos para troca de informações, assim você garante que não haverá bloqueios ou aumentar a complexidade do código.

Aqui você tem um exemplo para enviar e receber pacotes [UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20038943/47733)

Comment: Me falaram para fazer por Startup. Não intendi muito bem esse conceito. Vicê já ouviu falar?